# Display multiple attributes in mx:Tree

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

Is it possible to display multiple attributes in a mx:Tree component?
The XML looks like this:

```
<item comment="blabla" author="user1" date="21.05.2011">
    <item comment="blabla" author="user2" date="21.05.2011"/>
    <item comment="blabla" author="user3" date="21.05.2011"/>
</item>
```

I want each node to display the comment, author and date, on separate lines.

I am planning to use this to display something like the facebook wall: someone writes a message and the other users can comment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom ItemRenderer for this.

Checkout the Adobe livedocs:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_8.html

Cheers

Comment: I know about custom ItemRenderers, but I don't know how to access the other attributes except the label...

Comment: you do not know how to access the XML attributes or what do you mean exactly? could you elaborate?

Comment: Yep, the problem was that I couldn't access the XML attributes in my ItemRenderer. I was trying to access it like this: treeListData.comment. Silly mistake :| The correct way is treeListData.item.@attribute. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you were ok with all of the attributes on the same line, you could also use the labelFunction:

```
myLabelFunction(item:XML):String {
   return item.@comment + ' ' + item.@author + ' (' + item.@date + ')';
}
```

For another example, see:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/29/defining-a-custom-label-function-on-a-flex-tree-control/